# Understanding origin of the color of a menu icon

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, material-components

I am currently digging through the Google IO 2019 source code and there is one thing I can't figure out where it comes from: the color of the hamburger menu icon.

Here's a screenshot of the preview of `mobile\src\main\res\layout\fragment_codelabs.xml` ([source link](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/mobile/src/main/res/layout/fragment_codelabs.xml)):
[image]

And here is a zoom-in of the hamburger menu icon, one can easily see that it's at least not black:
[image]

The image source is `@drawable/ic_menu`:
[image]

The source code of `@drawable/ic_menu`(`mobile\src\main\res\drawable\ic_menu.xml`) ([source link](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/mobile/src/main/res/drawable/ic_menu.xml)) is

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:tint="?colorControlNormal">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M3,18h18v-2L3,16v2zM3,13h18v-2L3,11v2zM3,6v2h18L21,6L3,6z" />
</vector>
```

So here the `fillColor` is specified as `#FF000000` which is 100 % black and opaque (alpha FF). Yet the hamburger menu icon isn't displayed in black. So, where is the color that the hamburger menu icon is displayed in actually coming from?

Comment: Check `android:tint="?colorControlNormal"`

Comment: You can also use `android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar"` in your `Toolbar` where you can define something like `<style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/....</item>`
  </style>

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti: Thanks, you had the correct direction, but at the time of your reply I yet didn't know enough to follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to dig deeper into the styles, most likely it comes from default parameter of one of the parent of Activity theme. I'll try to show how I found it.

1. In the `\mobile\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` file, all Activities are inherited from `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`
2. `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.AppTheme" />`
3. `<style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">`
4. `<style name="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"/>`
5. `<style name="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light" parent="Base.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"/>`
6. `<style name="Base.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light" parent="Base.V14.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"/>`
7. `<style name="Base.V14.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light" parent="Base.V14.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">`
8. `<style name="Base.V14.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge" parent="Platform.MaterialComponents.Light">`
9. `<style name="Platform.MaterialComponents.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>`
10. `<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>`
11. `<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>`
12. `<style name="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat.Light">`
13. `<style name="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light">`
14. `<style name="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat.Light">`
15. `<style name="Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Light">`
16. `<style name="Base.V21.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light">`
17. There you can see that we're close `<item name="android:colorControlNormal">?attr/colorControlNormal</item>`, we need to go deeper.
18. `<style name="Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Platform.AppCompat.Light">`
19. There it is `<item name="colorControlNormal">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>` :)
20. But, we can go even further deeper, until we get to `<style name="Theme.Material.Light" parent="Theme.Light">`
21. There's `<item name="textColorSecondary">@color/text_color_secondary</item>`
22. `text_color_secondary.xml`

    `<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_enabled="false"
            android:alpha="?attr/disabledAlpha"
            android:color="?attr/colorForeground"/>
        <item android:alpha="?attr/secondaryContentAlpha"
            android:color="?attr/colorForeground"/>
    </selector>`
23. `<item name="colorForeground">@color/foreground_material_light</item>`
24. And in `colors_material.xml` it is `<color name="foreground_material_light">@color/black</color>`
25. And alpha is `<item name="secondary_content_alpha_material_light" format="float" type="dimen">0.54</item>`

So, to put it simply: the color of a menu icon is default theme **black** with **alpha 0.54**

Comment: wow, thank you so much. I will verify the complete way with more time tomorrow, but I did a short validation by creating a black with alpha 0.54 (or alpha 138 when on a scale from 0 to 255) and it is exactly the same as on the menu item. So it looks like your way is correct! Very likely will select your answer as the correct one, just let me further check tomorrow.

Comment: Sure :) the styles are very confusing

Comment: couldn't *yet* check completely but marked as correct answer :-) Did you also use Android Studio and Ctrl+click to follow the parents or did you find a better way?

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf Thank you, this is my first accepted answer :) yes, I had to pull the repo and Ctrl+click all the way

Comment: meanwhile followed the complete way myself looking from time to time to your result for checking/hints and can confirm your result. Learned a lot about styles and following them :-) hint: Ctrl+click to follow parents stops working for me when I upgrade to Android Studio 3.51. 3.5 works fine (with upgrading gradle plugin as android studio recommends for the google io app).

Answer (score 0):

In the below xml file, they set the style of the appbar

mobile\src\main\res\layout\fragment_codelabs.xml ([source)](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/mobile/src/main/res/layout/fragment_codelabs.xml)

```
    style="@style/Widget.IOSched.AppBar"
```

If you open the mobile/src/main/res/values/styles.xml [source](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/mobile/src/main/res/values/styles.xml)
you could find that definition of the style, it is general practise to have common style throughout the app to have uniformity instead of one-off TextViewStyle/Size/Design.

Comment: In the styles.xml they set only background und elevation for Widget.IOSched.AppBar. can't See how that Changes the color of the menu Icon?